# Subject line not visible in gmail inbox while sending email from phpmailer in php

Tags: php, html, gmail

I'm using the CodeIgniter Web Framework and trying to send HTML emails from the PHPMAILER library. When I receive the mail in my Gmail inbox it looks like this:

[image]

HIDDEN SUBJECT LINE

```
<span style="color: transparent; display: none; opacity: 0; height: 0px; width: 0px; font-size: 0px; --darkreader-inline-color:transparent;" data-darkreader-inline-color="">Taking a closer look at the Carbon Negative DeFi token Algorand&nbsp; |</span>
```

I added the simple text inside the body tag somehow Gmail is not showing up as a message preview but that didn't work.

EMAIL HEADER

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
```

MAIL FUNCTION

```
public function send_mail_using_php_mailer($message = NULL, $subject = NULL, $to = NULL, $type = NULL)
    {
        // Load PHPMailer library
        $this->load->library('phpmailer_lib');

        // PHPMailer object
        $mail = $this->phpmailer_lib->load();

        // SMTP configuration
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host        = get_smtp_settings('host');
        $mail->Port        = get_smtp_settings('port');
        $mail->SMTPAuth    = true;
        $mail->Username    = get_smtp_settings('username');
        $mail->Password    = get_smtp_settings('password');
        $mail->SMTPSecure  = get_smtp_settings('security');
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array(
                                   'verify_peer' => false,
                                   'verify_peer_name' => false,
                                   'allow_self_signed' => true));
        

        $mail->setFrom(get_smtp_settings('username'), get_smtp_settings('from'));
        $mail->addReplyTo('support@foodrive.ca');

        // Add a recipient
       $mail->AddAddress($to);

        // Email subject
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        // Enabled debug
        $mail->SMTPDebug = false;

        switch ($type) {
            case 'reset':
                $htmlContent = $this->load->view('email/reset', array('message' => $message), TRUE);
                break;

            case 'verify':
                $htmlContent = $this->load->view('email/email_verify', array('message' => $message), TRUE);
                break;  

            case 'confirmation':
                $htmlContent = $this->load->view('email/order_confirm', array('order' => $message['order'], 'menu' => $message['menu']), TRUE);
                break;

            case 'cancellation':
                $htmlContent = $this->load->view('email/order_cancel', array('order_details' => $message), TRUE);
                break;      

            case 'driver_assign':
                $htmlContent = $this->load->view('email/driver_assign', array('order' => $message) , TRUE);
                break;  

            case 'admin_alert':
                $htmlContent = $this->load->view('email/admin_notify', array('message' => $message) , TRUE);
                break;  
            
            default:
                $htmlContent = "NO TEMPLATE SELECTED! CONTACT FOODRIVE";
                break;
        }
        
        $mail->Body = $htmlContent;
        // Send email
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            // YOU CAN DEBUG HERE, WHETHER MAIL IS GOING OT NO. YOU CAN PRING THE "ErrorInfo" OF MAIL OBJECT
            return false;
        } else {
            // YOU CAN DEBUG HERE. WHETHER THE MAIL IS GOING OR NOT. YOU CAN ECHO HERE
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I don't know exactly what causes not to show message preview in Gmail, if anybody has a solution for this then please guide.

Comment: What made you think that such a "hidden subject line" was the way to achieve what you want? Is this documented anywhere, either by Google itself, or as a best practice?

Comment: No, I just want my users to preview the message before clicking the actual email, like I have multiple email send and just a quick look